# Optional type and Spring Data Rest Projections

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I've got a couple of classes like the following where a `Person` has an `Optional` `Employer`.

```java
    class Person {
        String getFirstName() {...}
        String getLastName() {...}
        Optional<Employer> getEmployer() {...}
    }

    class Employer {
       String getName() {...}
       String getAddress() {...}
    }
```

Using Spring Data Rest, I'd like to apply a projection to `Person` that also includes a projection of `Employer`.  Something like this.

```java
    @Projection(name="simple", types=Person.class)
    interface PersonProjection {
       String getFirstName();
       Optional<EmployerProjection> getEmployer();
    }

    @Projection(name="employer", types=Employer.class)
    interface EmployerProjection {
       String getName();
    }
```

However, what I'm seeing is that the `EmployerProjection` isn't getting used.  The `PersonProjection` is working, but it's behaving as if `PersonProjection` were defined like this.

```java
    @Projection(name="simple", types=Person.class)
    interface PersonProjection {
       String getFirstName();
       Optional<Employer> getEmployer();
    }
```

`EmployerProjection` is being ignored.  There seems to be something about the `Optional` part that's causing the problem.  If I change the return type of `getEmployer()` on both the Person class and PersonProjection to be `Employer` instead of `Optional<Employer>`, the `EmployerProjection` is picked up and it works.  Either `Optional` isn't supported in this case or I don't have the projections defined correctly.  Any ideas?  I'm using Spring Boot version 2.0.3.

Comment: saw this issue and I ended up changing `Optional<EmployerProjection>` to `EmployerProjection`. Apparently, spring doesn't detect projections if Optional is used in return type.